# imagecreatefromjpeg() works fine on one server and gives error on other

Tags: php

I have a script and it uses PHP functions like imagecreatefromjpeg()
I recently bought a new server and migrated all the files from old server to new. I have checked the code 100 times and it is same as it was on old server and all the files are migrated successfully but when run it gives the following error:

```
 Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: Cannot read image data in 

 Notice: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Read error! in
```

Is there anything which should be changed in server configuration because code works perfectly fine on other server.

Comment: does the image have `read permissions`?

Comment: yes.. its has read permission

Comment: hi.. i just checked. it is not able to read the images. while images have read permission

Answer (score 0):

You might try checking for differences in your PHP configuration between the old and new servers, in particular I would look at the following settings: upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, file_uploads, and maybe even memory_limit.

Answer (score 0):

Check those things:

1. The image has reading permissions
2. You are using the correct path (and not the old one) to open the image
3. The image was not corrupted during the migration (download on your pc and try to open it)
4. Check if the php configuration is different from the server you used before

Or try to debug separately the imagecreatefromjpeg on a test image, inserting manually the path, checking the existence via php and permissions and similar...

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem comes from the server which gives the error.

You can try changes your php.ini file's adjustments on the server.